# Unable to change ownership using chown even as root user

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, chown

Below is a snippet of my automation script, ownership gets changed for the directory (or)mount point - /deploy/umbro/$Client to  ind$Client:ind as expected, but on the other hand, ownership for the directory (or)mount point, under the case statements are not getting changed. 
Still remains as root:root

Not exactly sure where I have gone wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

Client=$1
Region=$2

sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1

#Mount point creation for nvme2n1

mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client

mount -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client
sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme2n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"') /deploy/umbro/$Client  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2 >> /etc/fstab

perm=ind$Client:ind
chown -R $perm /deploy/umbro/$Client

#Mount point creation for nvme1n1, based on region

case $Region in
  AUS)
    mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    chown -R ind$Client:ind /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    mount -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme1n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"')   /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs   xfs defaults,nofail 0   2 >> /etc/fstab
    ;;

  EUR)
    mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    chown -R ind$Client:ind /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    mount -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme1n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"')   /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs   xfs defaults,nofail 0   2 >> /etc/fstab
    ;;
 ......
 ......
esac#!/bin/bash

Client=$1
Region=$2

sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1

#Mount point creation for nvme2n1

mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client

mount -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client
sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme2n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"') /deploy/umbro/$Client  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2 >> /etc/fstab

perm=ind$Client:ind
chown -R $perm /deploy/umbro/$Client

#Mount point creation for nvme1n1, based on region

case $Region in
  AUS)
    mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    chown -R ind$Client:ind /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    mount -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs
    sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme1n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"')   /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/default/logs   xfs defaults,nofail 0   2 >> /etc/fstab
    ;;

  EUR)
    mkdir -p /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    chown -R ind$Client:ind /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    mount -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1 /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs
    sudo echo UUID=$(sudo blkid | grep /dev/nvme1n1 | grep -Eo [\"].*[\"] | awk '{print $1}'|  tr -d '"')   /deploy/umbro/$Client/checkpoint/arm/logs   xfs defaults,nofail 0   2 >> /etc/fstab
    ;;
 ......
 ......
esac
```

AWS EC2 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7, 
user - root

Strange observation is that, if I manually do the below steps, ownership gets changed recursievly till logs folder.

```
cd /deploy/umbro/$Client
chown -R ind$Client:ind checkpoint/
```

Comment: When you mount the fs on the directory, the directory is overshadowed by the root of the mounted fs. The permissions you set no longer matters, because that directory is hidden behind the new fs. You can chown after mount if you want to change the permissions on the fs root dir

Comment: @thatotherguy : spot on, I tried that after posting the question and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

chown after mounting worked. thank you @thatotherguy for the nice explanation.